# Synergy keystrokes from Win7 to Virtualbox debian running under Win7

Tags: linux, terminal, debian

I'm using synergy to use the keyboard of my main computer (Windows 7) for my secondary computer (Debian Linux running on a virtual box under Windows 7).

The Problem is, that I can't enter some special characters (like `@`, `[`, `{`, `\`) in my Debian system unless I change the keyboard-layout on my host-system to en-US.

I can however enter those characters in the Windows 7 client. The keyboard-layout on all 3 systems is de-DE.

Is there any way to circumvent this problem? It's really a pain in the ass for me to write with an American layout, since I'm really used to the German one and I make way too many mistakes, when I'm using the American layout.

EDIT:
I renamed the question to better reflect my problem, after I out, what the cause is. Also rewrote the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug reported in insufficient support for international keyboards.
http://synergy-foss.org/spit/issues/details/14/

How ever I have been using an Icelandic keyboard on both client/host and did not experience this problem. But my setup is Linux as primary and windows as secondary and from the information in the bug posted it looks like it might be an issue with win32 and especially if you are using more than one keyboard layout.

Comment: I'm using the same keyboard-layout on all OSes, namely `de-DE`.